# Powershell Hash Table Grouping

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory, hashtable

I have a CSV like below:

```
location,id
loc1,1234
loc1,1235
loc1,1236
```

Running $a = Import-CSV C:\File.csv | Group-Object "location" I get the following output:

```
Count  Name    Group
-----  ----    -----
3      loc1    {@{location=loc1; id=1234}, @{location=loc1; id=1235), @{location=loc1, id=1236}}
```

I would like to add all ID's to a single group (Using Add-QADGroupMember) but I can't figure out how to get a group of ID's for $loc1. It seems to be be grouping them correctly but I can't seem to parse the output into a single group. E.g $loc1 = 1234,1235,1236 that I can loop through.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky, but this will do it:

```
Import-Csv C:\File.csv | Group-Object "location" | %{Set-Variable ($_.Name) ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id)}
```

After running that, **$loc1**, **$loc2**, etc. will be arrays of all the ids for each location.

Comment: I _knew_ I was over thinking this. This is exactly what I was looking for! Having a variable for each location allows me to compare existing group members and update/remove as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`Group-Object` doesn't handle hashtables well, since the keys aren't real properties.

Assuming:

```
$csv = Import-CSV C:\File.csv
```

You should be able to do, for example:

```
$ids = $csv | %{ $_.id }
```

to get an array of the ID values.  You'd probably want to pipe through `Get-Unique` for location.

If you wanted to get the location for a single ID quickly:

```
$location = $csv | ?{ $_.id -eq 42 } | %{ $_.location }
```

If you wanted to get an array of all IDs for a single location quickly (I think this is what you want):

```
$loc1 = $csv | ?{ $_.location -eq 'loc1' }
```

For reference, if you wanted to get a hashtable mapping each location to an array of IDs:

```
$groups = $csv | %{ $_.location } | &{
    begin
    {
        $hash = @{}
    }
    process
    {
        $location = $_.location
        $hash[$location] = $csv | ?{ $_.location -eq $location }
    }
    end
    {
        $hash
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that what he wants is to get arrays of the IDs for each location, but `$loc1 = $csv | ?{ $_.location -eq 'loc1' }` isn't going to work. It's a little trickier than it looks at a first glance. **$csv** is an array of GroupInfo objects. Piping it through that **where** block will evaluate to null. He needs to get the **.Group** property of each element of **$csv**, which is a collection object with properties for each column in the CSV file; then pipe that collection object to `select -ExpandProperty id`, which produces an array of the values of the id property.

Comment: @AdiInbar No, they're only `GroupInfo` objects after being piped through `Group-Object`.  I am advising **not** to pipe through `Group-Object`.  It just complicates matters.

Answer (score 0):

And yet another option:

```
(Import-Csv c:\foo.csv | Group Location -AsHashTable).Loc1 | Foreach {$_.id}
```

And if you're on V3, you can do this:

```
(Import-Csv c:\foo.csv | Group Location -AsHashTable).Loc1.Id
```